# Convert float to string with precision and without tolerance

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

How can you convert float to string with specified precision without tolerance?
For example, with precision 6 get the following result.

```
40.432 -> 40.432000.
```

In a string the only value that I can get is 40.431999.

Comment: Seems that `40.432` doesn't have exact representation with floating point.

Comment: If you need exact arithmetic, don't use floating point numbers. That's inexact by design.

Comment: @Jarod42 most numbers don't. But the library should round it for you, so something else must be going on.

Comment: Decide on whether full precision is valid within the program (and only adjusted during output) or do you need to adjust the numbers within the program.

Comment: If you convert with a precision of 17, what do you get? Floating point isn't always exact as others are saying, but the closest representable value is actually *higher*: 40.4320000000000021600499167107045650482177734375. The only way you should be seeing this result is if your number is less than 40.4319995.

Comment: Search the internet for "fixed point math".  You could represent 40.432 as 40432 (integer).  Divide by 1000 when displaying.

Comment: `40.432` is in fact `40.43199920654297` [Demo](https://ideone.com/ZhkPL1), so rounding 6th digit 2 -> 0 resolving to `40.431999`

Comment: @Jarod42 I was basing my calculations on `double` not `float`, so my conclusions were incorrect - you get the prize.

Comment: The problem is incorrectly stated. In C++, `40.432` is a `double` constant, and `double` is widely implemented with IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point, in which `40.432` ought to produce 40.4320000000000021600499167107045650482177734375, which, when converted to decimal for printing with rounding to six digits after the decimal point, should produce “40.432000”. A `float` implemented with the 32-bit format would result in 40.43199920654296875, which would print as “40.431999”. OP ought to clarify whether they have a `float` or have the double `40.432`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't even think that's necessary at this point, the evidence points to `float` as stated in the question. Trying to print 8 total decimals from a data type that only supports 7 digits is going to end in tears.

Comment: If the value is a `float`, then no value closer to 40.432 than 40.43199920654296875 is possible, and this value is properly formatted as “40.431999”. If the value is a `double`, and it is not printing as “40.432000”, then it contains some value other than 40.4320000000000021600499167107045650482177734375, and the problem is that it is the result of computations that did not produce a value sufficiently near 40.432. (Alternately, OP’s C++ implementation is not using the common IEEE-754 formats, but that is unlikely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `float` data type which only has a precision of [at most 7.22 total digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) and sometimes as little as 6 digits, and you're trying to display 8 total digits (2 before the decimal and 6 after). As noted in the comments, the closest possible binary float to 40.432 is 40.43199920654296875, the second closest would be 40.432003021240234375.

You can get more digits by converting to the larger `double` type. Once you've done that you can round to the nearest 6-digit number. Note that if the `float` was generated by a calculation, rounding may actually create a *less* accurate result.

If you always know your numbers will be between 10 and 100, this simple code will work. Otherwise you'll need a more complex process to determine the appropriate amount of rounding.

```
float f = 40.432;
double d = f;
double r = std::round(d * 10000.0) / 10000.0; // 2 digits before the decimal, 4 after
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << r;
```

Note that the last 2 digits will always be zero because of the rounding.

See it in action: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f085e56c03ebeb73

Comment: You refer to a Wikipedia page in support of the assertion that `float` has a precision of seven digits, but I do not see that assertion supported in the page. It should not, as `printf("%.7g\n", 9.999979e9f)` yields “9.999978e+09”, with only six correct digits. (The “decimal digits” column in a table there is a measure of information, not of the number of digits preserved. The latter is applicable when discussing how many digits can be correctly displayed.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil nice counter example. I'm going to have to study that a bit to understand why it fails.

Comment: Suppose you have a rectangle that is 7.22 bricks long (and as wide as one brick is). Obviously, it can cover seven bricks—if you start at or near a brick boundary. But suppose you do not have a choice, and it starts at an arbitrary position. How many bricks does it cover? In the worst case, it starts just after a brick boundary, and .99+ of a brick length is wasted before getting to the next boundary, leaving only 6.22 and a bit to cover full bricks. So it covers only six bricks. Every floating-point binade compels a starting point relative to decimal numerals, and they are incommensurate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks again for the explanation. I've made an edit that hopefully improves the accuracy of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can you convert float to string with specified precision

You can use a string stream:

```
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6)  << the_value;
std::string str = strs.str();
```

> In a string the only value that I can get is 40.431999.

Your problem may be that there exists no exact representation for 40.432 in the floating point format that your system uses. Since you can never have a floating point value 40.432, you can never convert such value to a string.

It just so happens that the closest representable value to 40.432 is closer to 40.431999 than it is to 40.432.

You need to:

1. Either Accept that 40.432 ~~ 40.431999
2. Or use a floating point format that is precise enough to have a representation for 40.432 that is closer to 40.432 than it is to 40.431999, and is also precise enough for all other numbers for which you have a specific expected value. IEEE 754 double precision floating point happens to have a representable value closer to 40.432 than 40.431999.
3. Or stop using floating point. You won't have problems like this if you use fixed point or arbitrary precision data types.